# Python Capture Frame without stopping VideoStream

Tags: python, html, video-streaming, html5-video, eel

[Video Stream](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LXIO.png)

[Video Frame Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DWDc9.png)

Is there any way to get these both to run simultaneously? Like making the video stream run in the bg or something.

Video Stream:

```html
def gen(camera):
    while True:
        frame = camera.get_frame()
        yield frame


@eel.expose
def video_feed():
    x = VideoCamera()
    y = gen(x)
    for each in y:
        # Convert bytes to base64 encoded str, as we can only pass json to frontend
        blob = base64.b64encode(each)
        blob = blob.decode("utf-8")
        eel.updateImageSrc(blob, 'output')
```

Frame Capture:

```html
@eel.expose
def CamDetection():
    cap = cv2.VideoCapture(1)
    img_counter = 0

    if True:
        ret, frame = cap.read()
        if not (cap.isOpened()):
            print("failed to grab frame")
            # break
        # cv2.imshow("test", frame)

        # k = cv2.waitKey(1)
        # if k%256 == 27:
        #     # ESC pressed
        #     print("Escape hit, closing...")
        #     break
        # if k%256 == 32:
        #     # SPACE pressed
        img_name = "SKH_frame.png".format(img_counter)
        path = 'F:\Tensorflow\yolov5\webcamimage'
        cv2.imwrite(os.path.join(path, img_name), frame)
        print("{} written!".format(img_name))
        img_counter += 1

    cap.release()
```

Comment: Consider posting code inside of the question instead of adding links to images of the code.

Comment: Okay have added it! Thank you